# I am stuck with this code, why doesn't it work?

Tags: string, vb.net, strdup

Why does this code not give me the right output? I am expecting the
    output to be decomptxt = aa".

I typed in 02a (RLEText)"
"Function 'Compressdata' doesn't return a value on all code paths. A null 
    reference exception could occur at run time when the result is used."

Expected result: `decomptxt = aa`

**This is my code:**

```
x = 0
    For i As Integer = 1 To Len(RLEText)
        Dim st As String = RLEText
        NoChars = st.Substring(x, 2)
        Chars = st.Substring(x + 2, 1)
        decomptxt = String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(Chars, NoChars))


        Return decomptxt
        x = x + 3
```

Comment: Set Option Strict On and Option Explicit On, correct what's wrong with the code (e.g., `NoChars = Convert.ToInt32(st.Substring(x, 2))`) then post the whole procedure (a `Return` statement implies a Function, so what is `x = x + 3` doing there? It's unreachable. etc.)

Comment: For i As Integer = 1 To Len(RLEText)
            Dim st As String = RLEText
            NoChars = Convert.ToInt32(st.Substring(x, 2))
            Chars = st.Substring(x + 2, 1)
            decomptxt = String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(Chars, NoChars))


            Return decomptxt

I am new to programming and this is my first project. So I don't fully understand how to fix this problem. For example, if i input RLEText = 02a, then decomptxt should be aa, then if i input RLEText = 04w, then decomptxt should be wwww., Thanks for your help!

Comment: You should better edit your post rather than adding things like code in comments...

Comment: It's clear that you're new to this, that's why I suggested to set `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit On` (you'll find these settings in your Project's Properties, in the `Compile` panel). It's really important that you set these option. You can do the same using Visual Studio's general settings (`Tools -> Option -> Project and Solutions -> VB defaults`). Once you do, it will be also clear what you need to correct and your method will return what you expect it to. Post the whole code editing (see the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58258977/edit) link) your question, though.

Comment: x = 0  
        For i As Integer = 1 To Len(RLEText)  
            Dim st As String = RLEText  
            NoChars = st.Substring(x, 2)  
            Chars = st.Substring(x + 2, 1)  
            decomptxt = String.Join("", Enumerable.Repeat(Chars, NoChars))  
            Return decomptxt  
            x = x + 3  
It won't let me add it elsewhere so I'll post it here. I've switched on the strict and explicit options- what should happen now?

Comment: Are there any red squiggles in your code? Hold the cursor over the squiggle to find out what is wrong and fix it. All `For` blocks require a `Next` . Where is the `Next` in your code? Have you tried clicking edit on the SO page? There is a line below the tags "share edit close flag" You will be able to add to or change your question.

Comment: What is `RLEText` ? Is it the name of a text box?

Comment: Please do not put code in comments.  Click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58258977/edit) link beneath your question and add the code there.